# Use Absolute Naming for Worksheets when used with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following problem: In one of my excel files, i have the following worksheets: One in which I have a number of formulas, one with the data for the current month (which gets copied&pasted from another source into there), and a couple of worksheets that are used as some sort of archive.

I use a little VBA macro to move the data from the current month into the archive.

```
Sheets("Aktueller Monat").Cells.Cut
Sheets("1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

The moving part of it works fine. The problem is now that everytime i move the current month into the archive, it updates all the formula in my calc sheet so that they are now referencing the archive (which I don't want to, since the formulas should be calculating the new current month instead)

For example, this

```
=ZÄHLENWENN('Aktueller Monat'!$C:$C;"RSS*")
```

becomes this

```
=ZÄHLENWENN('1'!$C:$C;"RSS*")
```

and I don't want that.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does the archive still need the formulas, or do you just want the values?

Comment: @BenjiBoyWick I only need the values in the archive. The formulas, the current month (which the formulas sould **always** refer to) and the archive are three different worksheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Cut` and `Paste`, use [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [`PasteSpecial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx), followed by [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820947%28v=office.15%29.aspx) or [`ClearContents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835589%28v=office.15%29.aspx). In the example below I paste the values and number formats, but you can adjust this to your needs using different values of the [`XlPasteType` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
Dim oSourceRange As Range, oTargetRange As Range
Set oSourceRange = Worksheets("Aktueller Monat").UsedRange
Set oTargetRange = Worksheets("1").Range("A1")

oSourceRange.Copy
oTargetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
oSourceRange.ClearContents
```